# Как прочитать файл txt на android

Tags: android

Начал заниматься Android и не получается прочитать по дефолту Java файл txt.
public class Messiah extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messiah);}

public void onClickFindQoute(View view) throws IOException {
    TextView qouteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qouteTextView);

    int randQoute = (int) (Math.random()*203+1);
    int counter = 0;
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\leoge\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Messiah\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\leoge\\messiah\\messiah.txt");
    BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("_")) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == randQoute) {
            while (counter == randQoute) {
                line = fin.readLine();
                if (line.equals("_")) {
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
                qouteTextView.setText(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

06-26 17:53:01.006 2383-2383/com.example.leoge.messiah E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system

Comment: Вы на телефоне хотите прочитать файл который находится на вашем компьютере?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что у вас на телефоне есть файл в `C:\Users\\eoge\AndroidStudioProjects\Messiah\app\src\main\java\com\example\leoge\messiah\`?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо поместить ваш файл в папку `assets` проекта

```
public static String getStringFromAssets(Context context, String path) {

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream text;
    try {
        text = context.getAssets().open(path);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(text));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Открыл для https://developer.android.com узнал что не так делал) сделал через res/raw